# Spectral Clustering via sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis

When you use SpectralClustering via sklearn, it's output seems to be a list of the labels associated with the original list of node names. Is it possible to take their output and put my original labels into groups using sklearn.
So for example if my node list  is [1,2,3] and my output is [1 0 1], is there a way to go back to the actual names of my nodes and get back [1 3], [2].

Maybe I am asking this the wrong way or I need to look at another method to do Spectral Clustering, just looking for suggestions. Relatively new to python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing by notes you are referring to the observations.

For example :

```
from sklearn.cluster import SpectralClustering
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1, 1], [2, 1], [1, 0],[4, 7], [3, 5], [3, 6]])

print(X)
[[1 1]
 [2 1]
 [1 0]
 [4 7]
 [3 5]
 [3 6]]
```

And your node list is basically 1 to 6, one for every observation:

```
node_list = [i + 1 for i in range(len(X))]
print(node_list)
[1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

We cluster and get labels :

```
clustering = SpectralClustering(n_clusters=2,random_state=0).fit(X)
labels = clustering.labels_

array([1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

And split the list, many ways to do it, one way I can think of is to convert it to an array:

```
node_list = np.array(node_list)
[node_list[np.where(labels == i)[0]] for i in set(labels)]

[array([4, 5, 6]), array([1, 2, 3])]
```